# Encrypt and Decrypt route values MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, encryption

Which is the best practice to encrypt route values in parameters? Like encrypting id parameter value

1. Create custom action helper methods which encrypt route values
2. Create some extension methods which returns encrypted value
   [AES Encryption and Decryption](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AES-Encryption-Decryption-Cryptography-Tutorial-with-example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)